# sumif sumifs объединить

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть таблица `A|B|C`, где `A` – столбик с названиями, `B` — столбик с числами, `C` — произвольные даты из прошлого и бедующего.

и две функции:

```
SUMIF(A,criteria_1,B)
```

, `где criteria_*` — произвольное слово; `A` — столбик, в котором находятся `criteria_1`, `criteria_2`, `criteria_X`; `B` — столбик с произвольными числами.
, которая суммирует только те числа столбика `B`, в ряду которых столбика `A` есть `criteria_1`.

и

```
SUMIFS(B,С,">=10/1/2021",С,"<="&TODAY())
```

, где `B` – столбик с числами которые нужно суммировать; `С` — столбик с произвольными числами типа 12/31/2021.
, которая суммирует те числа столбика B, в ряду которых столбика `A` есть даты, которые попадают в диапазон с 10/1/2021 по СЕГОДНЯшний день.

По раздельности обе функции работают правильно. Подскажите, есть ли возможность всё это запихать в одну ячейку так, чтобы они выполнялись одновременно и в итоге я получал сумму чисел, которые входят в диапазон **с 10/1/2021 по СЕГОДНЯ** и только с **criteria_1**.

TODAY = 10/7/2021, в сумме я хочу получить 3042, а когда настанет 10/25/2021 – в ячейке должно стать 3324 (то есть +300)

[image: Как работают обе функции раздельно.]

Comment: Не пробовал `SUMIFS(B,A,criteria_1,С,">=10/1/2021",С,"<="&TODAY())`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, маг волшебник! Оно работает как надо 